# Reactive computed data in VueJs 2.0

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I have a paginated record set from a http response and want to further implement client side pagination on return paginated record set, thus I  have the following component markup

```
<td v-for="item in items">....</td> // only print 5 at a time
```

and in the default....

```
{
data: { return {
     itemsData:[] // populated from RESTful data in increments of 20 
     , offset: 0 // for internal pagination
      } },
computed: { 
  items: function(){ 
     return this.itemsData.slice(this.offset, 5); // re-populate over time as offset changes
  } 
},
methods: {
    getItems: function() {
     this.$http.get('/api/items/?page=' + this.page).then(response=>       
     { 
        this.itemsData = response.data.data; // json array and I al get back meta data  
        // for which i use in a mixin to calculate offset and page etc. 
        // for both client side and server side pagination
      }) // fetches records 20 at a time
    }
```

}
    .........

If `itesmData` is populated and then `offset` is dynamically changed. Shouldn't the component's template re-rendered with a new items collection?

Or should I be using a method instead? e.g.

```
<td v-for="item in paginated(itemData)">....</td>

{  
  ....
  methods: {
     paginated: function(items){
        var arr=[];
        for( var i = this.offset; i < this.offset + 5; i++)
           arr.push(item[i]);
        return arr;
     }
 }
```

How would the template be updated with the new array? Would I need to implement a watcher? on the computed data? or would the offset do?

UPDATE:

I tried to implement the pagination via competed and while I get the template to render the first 5..... in trying to re-render after updating offset does not fire.... `arr` seems to return empty even thought i am on the second page and `offset` is yet to reach `itemsData.length`

Can you iterate through a data array property OUTSIDE of the template? i.e. loop through `this.itemsData[i]` or `this.$data.itemsData[i]`???

Comment: Can you show us the code where you populate `itemsData`?

Comment: @JosephSilber updated

Answer (score 1):

You need to make following changes in your code:

```
computed: { 
  items: function(){ 
     return this.itemsData.slice(this.offset, this.offset + 5); // re-populate over time as offset changes
  }
}
```

As you can see from [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), slice takes two argument start and end, it will return a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included).